# EPUB Reader for the web in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, epub

I am new to angular 5,I have one epub file which I needs to show in a page.How can i show the epub  without using any iframes.

Comment: what have you tried? can you add any attempts?

Comment: I tried with futurepress/epub.js ,its working fine but thats not  available in angular 5.if you want i can give you the github demo app link for this epub.js

Comment: Try this one: http://www.blog.bdauria.com/?p=1117 
It may not fit perfectly to your technology stack, but at least you should see how to work with the epub.js library. Good luck.

Comment: its a javascript file/library, of course you can use it with angular

Comment: can you please give me the idea how can i integrate that js file in angular 5 and how can I call that functions in ts files.

Comment: I have same issue, please help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

A coworker and I did a Proof Of Concept of an Epub Reader in Angular (using [Angular-CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) v7). You can check it out here: [Angular-EpubReader](https://github.com/ntripathy/Angular-EpubReader)